# Probability of Rolling a 6 3 Times?

Tags: probability, statistics

You are to tosses a fair die, observing the topside of each throw, until you observe the third-six. What is the
probability that you stop tossing this die on your 18th-toss?

My thinking. 
Each roll you have a probability of 1/6 to roll a 6.

So in order to reach 18 rolls you would have probability of (1/6)^18.

Is this the probability of stopping by the 18th roll?

Would one need to multiply by (3c1)(2c1)(1c1)to account for order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You seem to have the right idea, but not quite grasped what you're counting.

In order to reach the third success on the eighteenth try, you must have *two successes* and *fifteen failures* in some arrangement among the first seventeen, then *one more* success on the eighteenth try.

So count the ways to select two from seventeen, then multiply by the probability of three successes and fifteen failures.

> #$$\mathsf P(X_3=18)~=~{^{17}\mathrm C_{2}}\cdot\tfrac{5^{15}}{6^{18}}$$

Comment: if you are selecting 2 from 17 shouldnt it be 17c2 not 17c3?

Comment: @sawreals2 Yed, it shoulf.

Comment: ikay, yhank you